# mediawiki transfer database in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, mediawiki-installation

I've established new mediawiki environment but I am getting the following error while migrating the sqlite db to the new environment. Also I upgraded to version of mediawiki 1.22 to 1.32. Is there Anybody has any idea about that situation or new steps to establish sqlite from older one.

```
Turning off Content Handler DB fields for this part of upgrade.
...have ss_active_users field in site_stats table.

An error occurred:
A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema 
updater after upgrading? 
Query: UPDATE  site_stats SET ss_active_users = '0' WHERE ss_row_id = '1'
Function: DatabaseUpdater::doActiveUsersInit
Error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database
Purging caches...<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Dahili hata - MediaWiki</title><style>body { font-family: sans-serif; 
margin: 0; padding: 0.5em 2em; }</style></head><body>
<div class="errorbox mw-content-ltr"><p>[Y@YbH@8tt-A18niaaU7SwQAAANQ] /mediawiki/mw- 
config/index.php?page=Upgrade   Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1506 of 
/var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has 
occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading? 
<br />
Query: DELETE FROM objectcache<br />
Function: DatabaseUpdater::purgeCache<br />
Error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database<br />
</p><p>Backtrace:</p><p>#0 
 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1476): 
Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database-&gt;makeQueryException(string, integer, string, string)<br />
#1 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1236): 
Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database-&gt;reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)<br />
#2 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(2964): 
Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database-&gt;query(string, string)<br />
#3 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(1071): 
Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database-&gt;delete(string, string, string)<br />
#4 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/installer/DatabaseInstaller.php(396): DatabaseUpdater- 
&gt;purgeCache()<br />
#5 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstallerUpgrade.php(65): DatabaseInstaller- 
&gt;doUpgrade()<br />
#6 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(272): WebInstallerUpgrade- 
&gt;execute()<br />
#7 /var/www/html/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(79): WebInstaller-&gt;execute(array)<br />
#8 /var/www/html/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(38): wfInstallerMain()<br />
#9 {main}</p></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem myself, I've shared steps with some guys who want to migrate the mediawiki with sqlite.

sqlite3 my_wiki.sqlite .dump > backup_sqlite.sqlite

The file which has been created by above should be migrate to new sqlite location and than run the that commands for migration old data.

sqlite3 mediawiki.sqlite < backup_sqlite.sqlite